# Exporting from MS SQL to CSV and keeping carriage return/line feed/tabs

Tags: sql, csv, export-to-csv

I have a field in one of my tables that has carriage returns, line feeds, and tabs.  I need to be able to export this field into a csv file and while keeping the format of carriage returns, line feeds, and tabs.

If I do a regular export, the csv file will treat all the carriage returns, line feeds, and tabs as a new cell and enter the data in the new cells.  I need to have all of this in one cell.  Is that possible?

I'm running sql server 2012 express.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Does your .csv file have to be delimited in a standard fashion? If it does not have to be in a standard fashion and you can pick any delimiter then you should be able to create a SELECT statement to wrap the selected delimiters/new line characters around your data. Then export the results to .csv format.

Comment: Thanks Sean. If I pick any delimiter, wouldn't that export my data into csv and put info into a new cell when the delimiter hits?   I'm trying to get everything into one cell.